# npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, popper.js, react-popper

When I place the command `npm update` for an existing React project, this is displayed:

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: Is that a specific problem? Did you try upgrading it? What happened?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1

Run the command `npm uninstall popper.js && npm i @popperjs/core` to remove the deprecated package and install their new Popper v2

Comment: afte run commandes  this is displayed : `npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`

Comment: bootstrap is depending on the deprecated popper, so you'll have to keep it if you want to use bootstrap.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't necessarily a problem, unless you are wanting to upgrade from the deprecated version.

If you wish to upgrade, just run `npm install @popperjs/core --save` and then `npm uninstall popper.js --save` from within your project directory to install Popper v2 and uninstall the deprecated version.

Answer (score -1):

Just write command in command-line and install new popper.js

```
npm i popper.js
```