# How to I can solve this problem to staring in my laravel project to install npm

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install, laravel-7, npm-request

After running `npm install` on project, I face this problem

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...3ec2605d1fc435f4d8651'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Najmun_Nafiz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-04T01_36_41_794Z-debug.log
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is pretty common when the packages in use are outdated/deprecated and no longer supported.

In your case **popper.js@1.16.1** checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60747896/5326191

For more info, go to [npm packages](https://www.npmjs.com/). Type in your package name to check the latest version and start updating your packages. Once complete, these errors will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Solved mine by upgrading my Nodejs version to 14.x.