# npm install command does not work with Laravel version 5.8

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, composer-php, laravel-5.8

I created a Laravel 5.8 project, and I want to install `npm`. So I typed `npm install` but I get this message:

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.3","npm":"6.14.6"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1055 packages from 500 contributors and audited 1058 packages in 149.498s

37 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

So I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747771/npm-warn-deprecated-popper-js1-16-1-you-can-find-the-new-popper-v2-at-popperj) related to my question, and he said run the `npm install @popperjs/core --save` command and after that `npm uninstall popper.js --save` in order to install Popper.

But as soon as I typed `npm install @popperjs/core --save`, I get this message:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @popperjs/core@2.5.2
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1059 packages in 9.5s

38 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

So now I don't know really what should I do for installing `npm`, so if you know, please let me know, I would appreciate that!

Thanks in  advance...

> UPDATE #1:

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.5.2"
    }
}
```

> UPDATE 2:

I removed `"popper.js": "^1.12",` at `package.json` and `node_modules` folder and typed `npm install` but again I get the same error!

[image: capture terminal]

Comment: Are you using an updated npm (NodeJS)?

Comment: @sta My node version is `v12.18.3`

Comment: @KamleshPaul See UPDATE #1 and thank u

Comment: @KamleshPaul Thanks for the idea, but again I get the same error, I put an UPDATE #2 on what I see on terminal :(

Comment: @KamleshPaul I guess so, but I wonder any kind of further feature will be missed or not...

Comment: @fojbiu no all feature will be include

Comment: @KamleshPaul Good to hear that, thanks for your effort <3

Comment: What makes you think that is an error? Other than for the warnings, it looks like it ran successfully.

Comment: There is no mention of the word "error" in any of the outputs you've shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  `"popper.js": "^1.12",` line from `package.json`

then remove `node_modules`

then run cmd `npm install`

Comment: Didn't work for me. That chokidar issue still persists

Comment: @Jim may be you have different issue